# Extracting source file string from xml file in a python script

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I need to extract source file from a xml file in linux for kvm backup. I am not sure how to iterate through the xml file and isolate the path, I tried using a variable method with regular expressions but that does not seem to work and I am not sure how I can properly extract proper line I need and what I made so far does not function properly including assigning the contents of the xml file to a variable with cat

import os
import re
#Create list of VMs on machine

vmlist = ['centos1','centos2','centos3','assign.1']

print(os.system('sudo virsh list --all'))
#Ask user which Vm they would like to backup
choice = input(f'Which available VM would you like to do a complete back up of ')

while choice not in vmlist:

```
    choice= input("Inavlid entry, please insert a correct VM name to continue ")

    if choice == 'centos1':
        xml=os.system('cat /etc/libvirt/qemu/centos1.xml')
        path= re.search('.qcow2$')
        print(path)
```

How could I proper isolate the path I am looking for within the file? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Python comes with an XML parsing library.

Comment: @Shawn Bro your comment just saved my life I been searching hours how to isolate data in xml all articles had some irrelevant function but nothing on parsing xml........